# Updating Image file in file Column in Parse Class on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

How to Updating Image file in file Column in Parse Class using already uploaded or available image on the Parse server. I am new to parse help me. I don't want to upload a new file instead I want to use already uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
Object.set({columnName: {"name": File.name, "url": File.url, "__type": "File"}});
```